# Yahoo! Pipes - update all sub-items?

Tags: yahoo, yahoo-pipes

I have tried for hours and found no solution for this problem.

There is a [Pipe I'm designing](http://pipes.yahoo.com/pipes/pipe.info?_id=2c572f1db5e815682f5f8bc21b122a8d) that pulls data from different RSS feeds. URLs for these feeds are located in a CSV file, so I'm able to parametrize this Pipe in the future.

Everything works correctly, however when I try to **add URL of the original feed** into each post returned by the **Fetch Feed loop**, I am only ever able to add this into the first one. I'm adding this information as *item.feed.feedUrl* in the second loop.

I need a solution where I may be able to add this information into ALL posts, so I can later identify the source for them.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Although I wasn't quite able to answer the question, I developed a solution that allowed me to return feed data along with original feed's URL for each first post.

To get an idea what I did, you are welcome to visit the final [FeedMerge Pipe](http://pipes.yahoo.com/pipes/pipe.info?_id=2c572f1db5e815682f5f8bc21b122a8d).

Answer (score 0):

May be there is a simpler solution but the following one should solve your problem.

**Short version:** use a sub pipe in your first loop

**Long version:**

***1)*** Build an other pipe (whose name could be "FeedMergeSub") with a unique parameter ("feedurl")

In this sub pipe  :

- fetch page for the feedurl parameter
- add a field "originalfeed" with the feedurl info

***2)*** Use your sub pipe  "FeedMergeSub" in your main pipe "FeedMerge"

In the first loop, replace the "Fetch feed" operator with your sub pipe ("FeedMergeSub") and pass it "item.link" as the "feedurl" parameter

Comment: thank you, I did think of this... however, the very reason for me for abandoning the idea was that I would need way more than 200 runs of the sub-pipe in 10 minutes... I will have lots of feeds in my database and this would 999 the subpipe in no time :)